# python: concatenating strings of a list within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it possible to take each separate string from each list and combine it into one string, then have a list of strings? Instead of a list of strings within a list?

`names = ['red', 'barn'], ['barn'], ['front', 'porch'], ['white', 'farm', 'house']]`

Expected output below:

`names = ['red barn', 'barn', 'front porch', 'white farm house']`

Here is what I have tried

`for name in names:
    names = " ".join(name)
print(names)`

the output of this code is

`white farm house`

Why does this only concatenate the last element in the list?

Comment: there are many ways, what did you try and what troubles with your solution?

Comment: You can't do this because the keys of the dictionary _must_ be unique. So you can have either `'horse': ['name=red', 'barn']` or `'horse': ['name=barn']`, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting names each loop, hence the last value of names is 'white farm house'.

Try this instead:

```
l_out = [' '.join(x) for x in names]
print(l_out)
```

Output:

```
['red barn', 'barn', 'front porch', 'white farm house']
```

Or you can do it the way you're trying:

```
l_out = []
for name in names:
    l_out.append(' '.join(name))
print(l_out)
```

Output:

```
['red barn', 'barn', 'front porch', 'white farm house']
```